# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta la app? Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, studio

me encantaría que me ayudaran, intenté colocar un ListView a mi proyecto de Android Studio, pero por alguna razón se cierra sin dejarme visualizar el listado, debugeando el objeto lo trae bien de la BDD, pero llego hasta "listViewListaJaulas.setAdapter(adaptador)" y no me deja seguir corriendo el debug. Agradezco que me explicaran como si fuera cavernícola prácticamente jeje.

(PD: es mi primer posteo, no me maten por la desprolijidad)

```
public class ActivityListaJaulas extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listViewListaJaulas;
private ArrayList<Jaula> listaJaulas;
ArrayList<String> listaResultados;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    iniciar();
    pJaula pJaula = new pJaula(getBaseContext());

    listaJaulas = pJaula.ListarJaulas();

    if(listaJaulas!= null && listaJaulas.size() > 0)
    {
        listaResultados = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<listaJaulas.size(); i++)
        {
            listaResultados.add(listaJaulas.get(i).getId()+ "-" + listaJaulas.get(i).getNumero());
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listaResultados);
    listViewListaJaulas.setAdapter(adaptador);
    listViewListaJaulas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String informacion="id:" + listaJaulas.get(i).getId() + "\n";
            informacion+="numero: " + listaJaulas.get(i).getNumero();
        }
    });
}

private void iniciar()
{
    listViewListaJaulas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Activity_lista_jaulas_list);
}}
```

En pJaula el código es este:

```
public ArrayList<Jaula> ListarJaulas()
{
    ArrayList<Jaula> lista = new ArrayList<Jaula>();

    this.seleccionarDatos("SELECT idJaula, numeroJaula FROM jaula");

    while(c.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        Jaula jaula = new Jaula();
        jaula.setId(c.getInt(0));
        jaula.setNumero(c.getInt(1));

        lista.add(jaula);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    c.close();
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falla porque listViewListaJaulas es `null`. En el método iniciar tienes que hacer el `setContentView` del layout donde has puesto el listView con el id `Activity_lista_jaulas_list`

Debería quedar algo tal que así

```
private void iniciar()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.nombre_del_layout);
    listViewListaJaulas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Activity_lista_jaulas_list);
}
```